# What experiment would confirm De Broglie equation on photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, momentum, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

If we want to check experimentally that, **for a photon**:

λ=h/p (De Broglie equation)

1. Has such experiment been carried out?
2. What is/would be the experimental setup?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Experimental_confirmation) doesnt show such protocol for a photon

EDIT: my question is badly worded, De Broglie's equation for a photon would be called Planck–Einstein relation

Comment: Isn't the photoelectric effect itself the confirmation of the de-Broglie relation for photons? I mean, in my understanding, the photoelectric effect first established (to some extent at least) this relation for photons and de-Broglie, explicitly inspired by the photon-case, then generalized it to the rest of the particles. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @DvijMankad your answer seems correct, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#Stopping_potential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. relativistic, one cannot prove the De Broglie's hypothesis, it should be a postulate.
2. non-relativistic, it can be proven by the photoelectric effect

Now de Broglie's hypothesis was that this equation for photons (photoelectric effect) not only works for massless particles, but for massive particles as well, this is how Schrodinger got the idea.

Comment: Could you elabrate on what you mean by the relativistic case ? Photons always move at relativistic speeds

Answer (score 0):

A thought experiment would be to measure the radiation pressure by reflection on a surface. You could use a torsion balance, in vacuum to avoid gas flow.

Comment: I think that analysis would work classically, too, though, so there is no appeal to $\hbar$.

Comment: I doubt this would be accurate enough to get the momentum per photon

Comment: @ManudeHanoi As Beth could measure the photon spin in 1935 in a similar manner it should be possible. Also I wrote _thought_ experiment. I think it is feasible but it will take some engineering. What is your doubt based on?

Comment: @my2cts had a quick look, for such an experiement to give you the equation, you'd need to measure the momemtum *for a known number of photons*. However in order to know how many photons are emitted in the first place, you need De Broglie equation. So you are stuck in circular reasoning (or so it seems, it's late here)

Comment: @ManudeHanoi Richard Beth did not worry about that in 1935. He knew the number of photons from the energy.

Comment: to get the number of photons from the energy you need De Broglie (his work was notorious enough to get Nobel in 1929)

Comment: @ManudeHanoi No. You need Planck or Einstein. Note that this thread is not about the question if De Broglie got the Nobel prize. I'd much rather hear the details of your "doubt".

Comment: As of my doubts, as long as you can count photons, i'm fine